# Extract all the numbers from a string with both letters and numbers

Tags: java, string

I am having trouble for my assignment to extract numbers from a string. I have to make a new integer with only the numbers from a string with both. An example would be:

String bearing = 'N30W';

I would then have an integer variable that would output '30'
as of now, I've tried:

```
  //digitsOfBearing = Integer.parseInt(bearing.replaceAll("[^0-9]", ""));
  //digitsOfBearing = Integer.parseInt(bearing.substring(1, bearing.length()-1));
  //digitsOfBearing = bearing.replaceAll("\\D+","");
```

But all my results have ended in the error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -2

Thank you

Comment: `Integer.parseInt(bearing.replaceAll("\\D", ""))` will work.

Answer (score 0):

This will do the thing.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "1fnvkk14718jafds";
    String digits = getDigits(str);
    long number = Long.parseLong(digits);
    System.out.println(number);
}

private static String getDigits(String str) {
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    for (char c : str.toCharArray()) {
        if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
            stringBuilder.append(c);
        }
    }
    return stringBuilder.toString();
}
```

Comment: 'getDigits(str)' is not a symbol.